# Simulate iPhone location(Fake GPS) using react-native

Tags: reactjs, iphone, react-native, expo

I want to simulate iPhone location similar to fake GPS location, but didn't find any suitable react-native library for this purpose. I've tried geolocation, expo location, react-native-maps but none of them covered the same feature.

Will be very helpful if someone can help me to fix this. I think I need some API to stop iPhone services or mock them to specific location data.